Azure HttpTrigger function with Blob() output issue with .NET 8.0 upgrade
I am having an issue with upgrading a repo to .NET 8. The issue is with an Azure HttpTrigger function that outputs to blob storage. I did notice that when I used the upgrade tool in Visual Studio to upgrade the function from .NET 6 to .NET 8 it did change the blob function name from Blob() to BlobInput(), which I believe is not right because I am outputting to blob.
In the .NET 6 version, the function looked like this:

In searching the web, I found that I needed to install the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage package (I'm running dotnet-isolated).
I'm assuming that I need to change the Blob() to BlobOutput() which only has a path parameter, so I need to define the connection in another way. Possibly defining it within the program.cs file or some sort of injection in the function itself?
If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it! Let me know if you need to see anything else. Thanks!

Provide your code in text format.

You can use [BlobOutput("container/{name}-output.txt", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]

Use BlobOutput() to implement HTTP Trigger Isolated Azure function output binding that outputs to blob storage.
 [BlobOutput("Container/{name}-output.txt", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]

I have created a sample .NET 8.0 isolated Azure function to implement output binding.
Code snippet:
public class Function1
{
     private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

     public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     [Function("Function1")]
     [BlobOutput("test-samples-output/{name}-output.txt", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]

     public IActionResult RunStyleHttpAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
         return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
     }
}

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_Connection_String>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}

.csproj:
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="6.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Blob got created in the Azure Storage container as below:

Content of the file:

Console output:
Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7194/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-12-21T05:20:34.550Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=4cfe55c4-fde1-4d0e-9af6-89a4b55844e5)
[2024-12-21T05:20:34.949Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-12-21T05:20:34.958Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-12-21T05:20:39.440Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-12-21T05:20:40.723Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=4cfe55c4-fde1-4d0e-9af6-89a4b55844e5, Duration=6217ms)

